# Maven liquibase plugin

Tags: maven, pom.xml, liquibase

I am new to Maven and Liquibase. For the past couple of days, I have been playing around with liquibase without Maven. I have tried generating changelog file with a new database and an existing database. Now I am trying to implement Maven and Liquibase using the plugin.

1. What is the advantange of running Liquibase with Maven from the command prompt rather than just running Liquibase from the command prompt?
2. Once I generate the pom.xml file and have src folder ready for my current project. I have the maven liquibase plugin in the pom file and liquibase.properties in resources. Will the changeLog file automatically get created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you would want to use Liquibase through Maven is to better fit with the rest of your build configuration. If you have your project set up with Maven and your CI servers using Maven it is usually easiest to run Liquibase through Maven as well to keep things simpler for you.

There is a generateChangeLog command that you can run either through Maven or through the command line which will generate a changelog file for you based on an existing database. This is often helpful when first starting to use Liquibase.

Once you have your changelog file, you would run liqubase update through the command line or Maven to apply your changelog to a database. As you need to make changes, the recommended approach is to add new changeSets to your changelog file then run liquibase update. This tends to be safer and more consistent than making a change to the database then running liquibase diffChangeLog to capture the change back to the changelog file.